# Android app installs but doesnt show up

Tags: android

I've been looking around and I can't seem to find an answer for this. My android app compiles correctly, no errors or anything, and it installs correctly, but it won't show up in the app drawer, and the "Open" button is greyed out. Here is my Main Activity

```
package com.dogger20011.app;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new                         

PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
  }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.Downloads) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
 }
```

Got any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MainActivity shouldn't make a difference, it's all about the manifest. Your main activity block should look like this:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.dogger20011.app.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Note that the `<intent-filter>` block needs to be nested **within** the `<activity>` block.

Answer (score 2):

You have your main activity placed after the intent filter which makes your mainActivity as the launcher. Please correct the XML like below (Basically, `MainActivitiy` related stuff) And also Removed the `maxSDKVersion` tag from teh `Uses-permission`

Finally it should be like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.dogger20011.app"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0.5" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

<activity
    android:name="com.dogger20011.app.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"/>

<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
<activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".AppActivity"/>
<activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".AppActivity_modD"/>
<activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".App2Activity"/>
<activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".AppActivity_ModD2"/>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I tried what you said and it still doesn't seem to work. I even copied and pasted to make sure I didn't screw anything up. Have any other ideas?

Comment: show me your latest manifest now. you can edit the above question and paste the latest stuff over there...

Comment: You scrwed up your manifest. The Intent Filter must be immediately ater your MainActivity as you've that activity as the main and it is the launcher of the app. Update that way as shows in my edited response

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried both ways, intent filter right after the Main Activity and at the bottom, neither worked. But I did just notice that you don't have the </intent-filter> tag. I tried that but get an error on the <activity below it. Not sure if you meant to do that or not.

Comment: Please use my latest manifest updated above. You've also placed MaxSDKVersion in the wrong place. I've updated both in my response above. Use my response manifest as it is in your code (copy/paste) and let me know how does that work.

Comment: Even copied and pasted your entire code and still no beans. Man this is extremely frustrating. What else could it be?

Comment: Share the entire Java code along with the latest manifest. U r screwing up somewhere definitely. Otherwise nothing should block you from the manifest point of view...BTW, do not get frustrated...that's programming and you'll learn only by your own mistakes...keep learning

Comment: Ramakishna is right and has been extremely patient in trying to help.

Comment: Mind if I just upload and send you the entire project? I'm not sure if that would be too much to deal with or not, but it might help you find the problem easier.

Comment: @JeremyMiller I'm not getting frustrated with him, I extremely appreciate the effort he has put in to helping me. I was just getting frustrated with the app not working, I am very new to this to its going to take some time, and I know that.

Comment: ..Share it in SO., If I'm not free someone else can help you in ways..that way your question is open to entire forum instead of depending only on me.

Comment: Alright. Just so you know I added my Main Activity to the original post if you want to take a look. I really appreciate ya man!

Comment: @RamakishnaBalla Brian DeWolff's answer worked for me, but I just want to let you know that I really appreciate you helping me out, means a lot to me! Thanks!